# Joomla Custom Module Development - Backend administration Extra requirement

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

I am currently in the process of developing a `custom joomla module` for one of my client’s requirement. As part of the administration panel of that module, I have created a radio button group, well in that group; I have two more radio buttons

My question for you leaders in the web arena is I need an option that "should display extra fields when I select one of the radio buttons"

For example: I have a radio button group named as 'No of fields'. In that group, I have two radio buttons named as 'Show', 'Hide'. I need an option which should display extra fields, when I select 'show' radio button

Is this equation possible? If yes, please post me your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior is not provided as a part of Joomla's default administration functions. You'll have to code it yourself and call that JS file when the module is opened in the backend. I would recommend you check the code used in [Mod_news_pro](http://www.gavick.com/news-show-pro-gk4.html) by Gavick. The module loads a custom JS file that add a lot of custom functions and layout options that wasn't available in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, just create a custom element checkout the official docs:

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type